# India to United States and then to Canada - Any Problem with Study Permit

Tags: canada

I m citizen of India and I just got my Student Visa . Now If I want to Spend some days in United States before going to Canada . So , this will cause any problems with my study permit as I m not coming to canada from my native country. Because we get the study permit on Canada Airport.

Answer (score 1):

Canada does not care what country you travel from. You can get your study permit at any airport of entry. The main thing you need to be concerned about is that your letter of introduction specifies the last date which you can enter Canada to get your study permit. You must do so on or before that date.